# Spring initializr project doesnt work with multiple errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Initializr to create a simple web project. I have selected both Web and Devtools modules on the website and created my project.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I already tried running the project as maven install, build, clean and performed a maven update with and without forcing the update of snapshots and releases. Nothing changed. Also I simply ran the application to see if it would work.

**After importing the project to eclipse, I try to run the SpringBootApplication as a java application and get the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

**below, usually happens after maven clean**

> Error: Unable to find and load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication

**below, usually happens after maven test and maven install**

> [INFO] Running com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests [ERROR] Tests
>   run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.111 s <<<
>   FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests [ERROR]
>   initializationError(com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests)  Time
>   elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/util/ClassUtils Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils

I even changed the target JDK of the project (i'm using JDK version 1.8) since maven test and install were giving me errors that I might be running the project on a JRE instead of a JDK.

Really no idea what this error means and I have tried google'ing the error to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of some of the corrupted jars so delete `.m2` repository and run `mvn clean install` and it works..!!

If you are window user then path for the .m2 repositoy will be `C:\Users\{username}\.m2`

Ensure that maven is installed on system or using eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Run "mvn dependency:tree" on project and check if you have multiple spring versions, if yes check the compatibility between the version you are using and the other libs you are using. If the desired dependencies not found delete repository under .m2 directory and run the maven commands again.

Comment: sorry, how do I run the mvn depencency:tree command? Do i add the maven installation to my path variable?

Comment: If you are in IDE like eclipse right click on project and run as -> Maven build (2nd one) and enter depencency:tree.

Comment: thank you, I ran it and it had multiple spring versions. to be safe I deleted the .m2/repository and restarted the maven installs and now it is working. thank you very much